# Asterisk (Trixbox CE) sound to low in message2email

Tags: email, asterisk, trixbox

Hy in Asterisk (Trixbox CE) latest version, we receive message to our email in WAV. But the sound it's too low. Where can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the gain on recorded messages by setting "volgain" in voicemail.conf.  For example add "volgain=7" to your voicemail.conf and test.  Please be aware that volgain requires sox to be installed.